# How do you edit lifecycle phase without command line (Maven)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to use Maven with my project in Eclipse and have the plugin installed but i get an "unknown lifecycle phase" error when i try to run the project. After doing some research it seems like i need to edit this configuration via command line. But apparently i would need to download the standalone maven installation to do this. Is there a way to edit the phase from Eclipse without command line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mystuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>stuff</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please attach your pom file

Comment: just edited the post. Also is there a reason why converting my project to a maven project didn't auto generate one?

Comment: try run it from cmd with "mvn clean package" first

Comment: "mvn is not recognized as a command"

Comment: If you trying to run Maven from command line you need to install it on command line. http://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: @khmarbaise i guess that was the point of my question. Do i need to install the command line version to use Maven or can i just use it with the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: I always recommend having Maven installed on command line but you can use the part in Eclipse but there might be differences. The message `Unknown lifecycle...` could be cause if you try to run Maven from Eclipse and didn't defined something in the line `Goals: ..`...